# Set a specific text color for Japanese, document-wide

Tags: formatting, color, cjk

I am writing a document (more specifically, a lexicon) which mixes two languages: a European language, and Japanese.

I use XeLaTeX (UTF8 source file) with the `xeCJK` package to handle the Japanese. Some of you are probably going to say that this is not optimal, but I have tried several solutions and this is the most seamless. `xeCJK` may not be ideal for 100% CJK docs, but when it comes to handling CJK parts in an otherwise non-CJK text it seems the least bad to me (by far).

What I’d like to do is setting the text color for Japanese script document-wide. Non-Japanese characters should not be affected and remain black. `xeCJK` already allows to set a specific font for CJK parts document-wide, with the `\setCJKmainfont` command. I’m looking for something similar for text color.

I had a look at the `xeCJK` documentation but couldn’t find a way to achieve this (plus, it’s only available in Chinese which doesn’t help, to be 100% honnest).

**EDIT:** Here is a very short exemple.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

% Setting a specific font for Japanese only.
\setCJKmainfont{Kozuka Gothic Pro}

% Anything similar for text color?
% ?

\begin{document}

Hello everyone! In this document, some sentences will be in Japanese.
これも読めたら日本語が分かりますね。

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code, just to play with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the `\setCJKmainfont` command of the [`xeCJK` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xecjk) internally uses [`fontspec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), so you can use fontspec's `Colour` (or `Color`) option. Read the [fontspec documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) (section *14.1 Colour*, as of the current version 2017/02/12 v2.6) for details and warnings. For example, you can use “a six-digit hex colour RRGGBB” (below I changed your font to one I have):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont[Colour=EE22AA]{Noto Sans CJK JP}

\begin{document}

Hello everyone! In this document, some sentences will be in Japanese.
これも読めたら日本語が分かりますね。

\end{document}
```

[image: xecjk with colour]

Comment: Perfect! I didn't expect the solution to be that simple.